# Sencha localStorage.getItem() returns null in model

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In my model, I have the following code:

```
Ext.define('Proximity.model.CandidateblocklistModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
    config: {
        store:'Proximity.store.CandidateblockStore',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'id' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'img', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'designation', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'summary', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'experience', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'industry', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'functionnml', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'role', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : Proximity.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/index.php/candidate/getcandidateblock',
            withCredentials: false,
             useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            extraParams: {
                "id": localStorage.getItem('id')
            },
            reader : {
                    filters: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property: 'name'
                    })
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The id in the local storage is already set before calling this model. I can see the id in localStorage by inspect element in Chrome, and I did get the value of it in other section. But I only can't get it in my model when I am trying to use it in proxy. I want to get data from my web service based on the value of the localStorage.

Code in my proxy:

```
extraParams: {
    "id": localStorage.getItem('id')
},
```

I want to get the id from localStorage here.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code works

```
proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : Proximity.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/index.php/candidate/getcandidatebest',
            withCredentials: false,
             useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            extraParams: {
                id: localStorage.getItem('id')
            },
            reader : {
                    filters: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property: 'ind_id',
                        property: 'fun_id',
                        property: 'role_id',
                        property: 'id'
                    })
                ]
            }
        }
```

and then use the filtering facility of store to pass the localstorage value. To do that give filter permission `remoteFilter: true,` this.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh i found an awesome trick. Instate of  setting `extraParams` in your Model, set it in the store of the same model.
My new code is as follows.
`Ext.define('Proximity.model.RecruiterbestlistModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        store:'Proximity.store.RecruiterbestStore',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'img', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'company', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'summary', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'address', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'industry', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'functionnml', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'role', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : Proximity.util.Config.getBaseUrl() + '/index.php/recruiter/getrecruiterbest/',
            withCredentials: false,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            reader : {
                    filters: [
                    Ext.create('Ext.util.Filter', {
                        property: 'ind_id',
                        property: 'fun_id',
                        property: 'role_id'
                    })
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});`

Look i have removed the code

`extraParams: {
    "id": localStorage.getItem('id')
},`

from Model. And in my store i have added

`listeners: {
    beforeload: function(store){
       this.getProxy().setExtraParams({
          id: localStorage.getItem('id')
        });
    return true;
},`

So my new store code is as follows

`Ext.define('Proximity.store.RecruiterbestStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.recruiterbeststore',
    config: {
        model: 'Proximity.model.RecruiterbestlistModel',
        autoLoad: true,
        remoteFilter: true,
        storeId: 'recruiterbeststore'
    },
    listeners: {
        beforeload: function(store){
           this.getProxy().setExtraParams({
              id: localStorage.getItem('id')
            });
           return true;
        }
    }
});`

And its solved my problem.

> But now i am having another issue. after running `sencha app build native`(using cordova bild), again i am having same issue, the `extraParam` are not added to proxy request.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I am having another issue. after running `sencha app build native`(using cordova bild), again i am having same issue, the `extraParam` are not added to proxy request.

Please hemp mt to solve this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: yes as i am new in stackoverflow, i didn't know how to link

Comment: When you are typing in your question, there is a link icon (a little globe with an arrow). You can use that to link to this question.

Comment: OK @EdCottrell Thank You so much.... I will keep this on my mind. Thank You so much.